# How to forward a call to a member function template that can be const or non const depending on the template type?

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

I have something similar to this (stripped down example to the relevant points)

```
struct Foo
{

    template <typename T>
    constexpr std::enable_if<someTrait<T>::value ,T>::type& get() const { return something(); }

    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if<someOtherTrait<T>::value ,T>::type& get() { return somethingDifferent(); }

    class Nested
    {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        T& get() { return foo.get<T>(); }

    private:
        Foo& foo;
    }
}
```

e.g. `Foo::get` evaluates to a const constexpr function or something completely non-const depending on the template type.

Now I want to be able to do this

```
class Bar : public Foo::Nested
{
    void nonConstFn()
    {
         auto& a = get<TypeA>();
         //...
    }

    void constFn() const // <===== Won't compile
    {
         auto& a = get<TypeA>();
         //...
    }
}
```

It's obvious that `Bar::constFn` won't compile as it calls the non-const function `Foo::Nested::get<TypeA>` – even if `TypeA` would satisfy `someTrait` and call the const function `constexpr Foo::get<TypeA>() const` again in the end.

Leaving the constexpr aside for now, how do I propagate the constness of the called function in my nested class' function template? I tried simply overloading it with a const and non-const version of `Nested::get` which solves it for clang on macOS but fails with MSVC in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows, which is unfortunately a required build target.

Note that the original example contains a lot more than just two versions of `Foo::get` so I'd like to avoid repeating all versions in `Foo::Nested` but forward it with one or two function templates if possible

Edit: I tried the proposal to use

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto get() const -> decltype(foo.get<T>()) { return foo.get<T>(); }

template <typename T>
constexpr auto get() -> decltype(foo.get<T>()) { return foo.get<T>(); }
```

[on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/jxehYq) which seems to compile fine for current MSVC versions but fails with Visual Studio 2015 MSVC 19.0, so this is no option

Comment: please always add the language tag

Comment: You done most of the work by stripping down your code to just the relevant parts. You just need to create an actual [mre]. I want to answer you and for that I need to test my solution, but I don't have a code that compiles to start from. First I need to make your code compile (the `Foo` part) which is something you should have done. If not for our time, think about potentials answers you are not getting because people just move on when they see they have to do your work in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of you need `enable_if::type` for the SFINAE to work.

To get to your question you need to overload `Nested::get`:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo
{
    template <typename T>
    constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, T>&
    get() const
    { return something(); }

    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T>&
    get()
    { return somethingDifferent(); }

    int& something() const;
    float& somethingDifferent();

    class Nested
    {
    public:
        Nested();

        template <typename T>
        constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, T>&
        get() const { return foo.get<T>(); }

        template <typename T>
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T>&
        get() { return foo.get<T>(); }

    private:
        Foo& foo;
    };
};
```

```
class Bar : public Foo::Nested
{
    void nonConstFn()
    {
         [[maybe_unused]] auto& a = get<int>();
         [[maybe_unused]] auto& b = get<float>();
    }

    void constFn() const
    {
        [[maybe_unused]] auto& a = get<int>();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your remark, I edited the original post to use enable_if::type – I simply forgot it when writing down the example ;) Regarding your solution: I'd like to get a solution working without explicitly overloading `Foo::Nested::get` with all signatures of `Foo::get` if possible somehow as there a some more than just two overloads in the real world scenario. Also added that to the original question

Answer (score 0):

You need const and non-const overload in `Nested`, you might avoid to repeat all overload/SFINAE with another (simple) SFINAE:

```
class Nested
{
    Foo& foo; // Should be declared before the decltype usage
public:
    Nested();

    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto get() const -> (decltype(foo.get<T>())) { return foo.get<T>(); }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto get() -> (decltype(foo.get<T>())) { return foo.get<T>(); }
};
```

Comment: While this seems to be working with even the oldest MSVC version available on godbolt.org https://godbolt.org/z/jxehYq unfortunately MSVC 14.0 fails with C2668: 'Foo::Nested::get': ambiguous call to overloaded function...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following problem, which is meaningless but proposes a solution to yours. You have a class with two functions and an invoker for them

```
class A
{
public: void foo() { printf("foo"); }
public: void foo() const { printf("foo const"); }
public: void invoke() { foo(); }
}
```

If you do `A().invoke()`, you will get `foo` obviously. If you want to force to execute the `const` type function, how do you achieve that? OK, you make the following change
`A::invoke() { const_cast<const A*>(this)->foo(); }` and that's it.